# Failed to find Build Tools revision 24.0.1 with react-native

Tags: android, android-studio, react-native

I've just installed React Native and Android Studio. I an on ubuntu 14.04 LTS and I am trying to run

```
react-native run-android
```

But I have an error like this

```
Starting JS server...
Running /home/marta/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081
error: no devices/emulators found
Could not run adb reverse: Command failed:/home/marta/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081
Building and installing the app on the device (cd android && ./gradlew installDebug...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> failed to find Build Tools revision 24.0.1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 6.992 secs
Could not install the app on the device, read the error above for details.
Make sure you have an Android emulator running or a device connected and have
set up your Android development environment:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/android-setup.html
```

I also checked

```
android list sdk -a
```

and I installed

```
Installing Archives:
Preparing to install archives
Downloading Android SDK Platform-tools, revision 24.0.1
Installing Android SDK Platform-tools, revision 24.0.1
Stopping ADB server succeeded.
Installed Android SDK Platform-tools, revision 24.0.199%)
Stopping ADB server succeeded.
Starting ADB server succeeded.
Done. 1 package installed.
```

And this is how my build.gradle file looks like

https://i.stack.imgur.com/u3x02.png

Do you have any idea what is wrong?

Sorry for not posting photos but apparently I need 10 reputation something.

Comment: `error: no devices/emulators found`... Run `adb devices`. Is there a connection?

Comment: Then below that... `Make sure you have an Android emulator running or a device connected and have set up your Android development environment:`

Comment: Although... according to your build.gradle, you are using `23.0.1`, so that error doesn't really make sense.

Comment: Possibly you have build tools revision 24.0.1 installed but in your gradle you declared build tools revision as 23.0.1. This is a merely speculation without more info from you. Can you please open Android SDK Manager and check which components are installed on your computer?

Answer (score 2):

Run:

```
android
```

in your sdk/tools directory to open the Android manager.   Pick  "SDK build tools version 24.0.1" and install it.  You need to do that using Android manager and not Android Studio which install a versión that react cant detect.

Answer (score 0):

I solve this problem.

```
android list sdk -a
```

This gave me list of packages available for installation and then I choose what I needed.

```
android update sdk -a -u -t [number from list of what I wanted to install]
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I suffered from similar error, and the reason was that I deleted  SDK build tool 24.0.1 after installing SDK build tool 24.0.2.

I found another way to fix the problem from here: http://www.garasiku.web.id/web/joomla/index.php/android/91-android-studio-2-1-3-failed-to-find-build-tools-revision-24-0-1

Simple copy & paste.

```
 1: Change project view to Android
 2: Go to Grandle Scripts and open "build.gradle (Module:app)" 
 3: change buildToolsVersion "24.0.1"  ->    buildToolsVersion "24.0.2" 
        ...
        android {
            compileSdkVersion 24
            buildToolsVersion "24.0.1" 
        ...
 4. Sync your project
```

This works well for me.

Answer (score -1):

Set proxy for your gradle.properties in the android folder. It will download Build Tool automatically for you:

```
systemProp.http.proxyHost=proxyHost
systemProp.http.proxyPort=proxyPort

systemProp.https.proxyHost=proxyHost
systemProp.https.proxyPort=proxyPort
```